# How to call parent method from model controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have one controller named "contractController"

**contractController** contains a method **save()**

**contractController** opens one model window with controller named "**PopUpcontroller**"

from **PopUpcontroller** i want to call save method on **contractController**

tried to call save method like `$parent` but nothing works.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Angular UI Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), then, make use of the "resolve" attribute when you call $modal.open().

Whatever you add to resolve, will be available if you hook it up as a dependency injection.

In the example on their page, the "item" is available as below because it is hooked up in "resolve".

Resolve:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

Use:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two controllers are nested so that:

```
<div ng-controller="contractController">
   <div ng-controller="PopUpcontroller">
   </div>
</Div>
```

you can just call $scope.save() on the popUpController and it automatically goes up to find a parent with that method (till the $rootScope).

if they are not nested you should use the services in order to perform the communication among controllers

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the popup is created from `contractController`'s scope if you want to retain its prototype. How are you creating the popup?

Something like this in Angular UI Boostrap (I don't use it but the API should accept it):

```
$modal.open({
    scope: $scope,
    /* ... other opts */
});
```

Comment: function PopUpcontroller($scope, $rootScope, $modal, authen, contractService) {
...
PopUpcontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$modal', 'authen', 'contractService'];

Comment: Looks like you're using Angular UI Bootstrap's `$modal`, correct? You need to pass your controller's scope into its `scope` option.